# C++ Builder 2009 - i18n - Quick Reports Exception - Class TQRPDFFilter not Found - When Change Format

Tags: windows-7, internationalization, c++builder

Using Win7, C++ Builder 2009 I have a project that I am able to compile and run without any issues when my region and language format is set to "English (United States)".

When I change the format to "Italian (Italy)", my program compiles then I get an exception that "Project .exe raised exception class EClassNotFound with message 'Class TQRPDFFilter not found'."

Nothing else changes in the program or paths, just the system change and I get this exception. I checked both the include and lib paths and they are setup correctly.

Comment: Does anyone know if changing the region format changes paths at all? I know other versions of windows will display "Program Files" differently... but not sure if changes these settings will change anything beyond the Date/Time formats and other settings shown in the additional settings button.

Comment: In the additional settings, I see that list separator is "," (comma) for Hebrew. Where is is ";" for Italian and "," (comma) for English US. I can run my program properly when my setting is set to Hebrew and English... makes me think the issue is related to the list separator... Will post an answer with the solution if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while since I asked this question. I'm following up, just as a reference. I believe  the issue was based on the import paths our projects use. We have a "common" set of code which is shared between some projects. The common source has references to TQRPDFFilter where the specific project does not. By changing the path order, putting common at the least priority, I got past my problem. This does not answer the question as far as why it was blowing up with the different language, but might give some insight to others on how to get past it, if they come across similar setups.